# nano editor line breaks

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, nano

I am trying to learn nano installed on my server (ubuntu 1204), but the problem is whenever I open a file in nano editor it opens the file (say a shell script) as one big line rather than with line breaks which fit the screen.

Is it possible to open files with linebreaks in nano? I have tried googling this problem, but couldn’t find anything which works.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you use to write these shell scripts?

Comment: And does the file show up as `line1\nline2` or just `line1line2`?

Comment: @Blender: no, it has this irritating $ sign at the end of the screen..

Comment: ok I solved it - hitting Ctrl+J shows the lines "broken"

Comment: the q belongs on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ctrl+J and the lines "broken".

Answer (score 0):

Toggle soft line-wrap in Nano:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

("Alt" key is the same as "Meta" key on Linux.)

Display a list of keyboard commands:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>